# How do I select next row from a DataFrame based on condition?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to select next row when the condition is true.

In SQL, I would use:

```
FROM [dbo].[table1] where Num IN (select Num + 1 from table1$ where Status='start')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

To select rows where `Status` is equal to `start`:

```
selected_rows = df[df['Status'] == 'start]
```